# Rails: Compiling URL with variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

I'm looking to redirect users to another website, and include their user id in the link.
The problem is that the url is different for each record.

The desired URL: ..../index.php?user_id=123
In another url, it might be: ..../index.php?user=123&foo=true

The desired form entry: http://www.google.com/index.php?user_id=#{@user.id}

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance!
Mitch

Answer (score 0):

Insert the ID in a normal link tag:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/index.php?user_id=<%= @user.id %>">Link text</a>
```

Or create the link in a helper, model method, etc:

```
def google_url(id)
  "http://www.google.com/index.php?user_id=#{id}"
end

<a href="<%= google_url(@user.id) %>">Link text</a>
```

There are a few other options, I suppose.

Comment: How would I use this in a redirect_to @campaign.link in the controller? - because the location of the user.id is always moving, depending on the campaign/link.

Comment: @user1175331 It's... moving? Are you asking "How do I replace a value in a string"?

Comment: Yep. Seems I was asking how to replace a string value. I was trying to do it immediately in the process, by using #{current_user.id}, instead of using gsub later!
Fixed. Thanks so much for your help!